# What is the probability that the distance between any 2 consecutive points on the line is less than the given minimum distance, d?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

**Question:**
Given a line segment $L$ and $n$ random points on it. Assuming the points are uniformly distributed over $[0, L]$. What is the probability that the distance between any 2 consecutive points on the line is less than the given minimum distance, d?

**Attempt:**

This question came from my curiosity, but my attempt is as follows:

To calculate the probability that the distance between any two consecutive points on the line is less than the given minimum distance $d$, we need to consider the total number of possible arrangements of the $n$ points on the line, as well as the number of arrangements that satisfy the condition.

The total number of possible arrangements of the n points on the line is given by the number of ways to choose $n-1$ points out of $L$, which is given by the binomial coefficient: $$C = {L-dn+1 \choose n-1}$$

Now, let's consider the number of arrangements that satisfy the condition. To do this, we can imagine dividing the line segment into small intervals of length $d$. For the distance between any two consecutive points to be less than $d$, each interval must contain at most one point. Therefore, the number of arrangements that satisfy the condition is given by the number of ways to choose $n$ or fewer intervals out of $(L/d)$ intervals, which is again given by the binomial coefficient:
$$S = {L/d + 1 \choose n}$$

Finally, the probability that the distance between any two consecutive points on the line is less than d is given by the ratio of the number of arrangements that satisfy the condition to the total number of possible arrangements:
$$P = \dfrac{S}{C}$$

I've tested the theoretical calculation with a Monte Carlo simulation. The results do not match. Hopefully, someone can provide an answer to the query. Thanks.

EDIT: For reference, using Monte Carlo simulation with the parameters $n = 10, L = 20, d = 2$, and $10^6$ trials the estimated probability is 0.002.

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that at least one of the $n-1$ distances is greater than $d$, or the probability that a randomly selected one of the $n-1$ distances is greater than $d$?

Comment: @BrianTung Perhaps the Monte Carlo algo steps will clarify your question. 1. generate n random points
2. sort the points by order of smaller first
3. calculate the distances between consecutive points
4. count how many distances are smaller or equal to the minimumDistance.

Comment: You approach of dividing the line into intervals and requiring each interval to contain one point is incorrect. Imagine two consecutive intervals and one point is at the beginning of the first interval and the second is at the end of a second. The distance between points will be greater than $d$

Comment: Steps $1, 2, 3$ were never in doubt. I was asking whether in $4$ you want the probability that at least one of the $n-1$ distances is greater than $d$, or the probability that a randomly selected one of the $n-1$ distances is greater than $d$ (equivalently, the expected proportion of distances greater than $d$). It sounds like the latter? However, with $10$ points on an interval of length $L = 20$, how could only $0.002$ of the distances be greater than $2$? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @BrianTung The question is asking for the probability of all $n-1$ distances being less than $d$.

Comment: Which is the same as asking for the probability that the *maximum* of the $n-1$ distances is less than $d$.

Comment: Ahh! OK, that was not so clear to me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is described is the probability that the *maximum*, $x_{max}$, of the $n-1$ distances is less than $d$. This question was *almost* answered in a [CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163147/214015). The difference here is that the distance from 0 to the first point and the distance from the last point to $L$ are not considered. To exclude those two intervals, change the $k+1$ term in the summation and binomial coefficient to $k-1$ (or change $n+1$ to $n-1$ using our notation):

$$P(x_{max}\leq d)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose j}(-1)^j(1-jd/L)_+^n$$

As a function in R:

```
f <- function(n, d) {
  j <- 0:(n - 1L)
  jd1 <- 1 - j*d
  jd1[jd1 < 0] <- 0
  sum(choose(n - 1L, j)*(-1)^j*jd1^n)
}

L <- 20
d <- 2
n <- 10L

f(n, d/L)
#> [1] 0.00199584
```

Check against a simulation with $10^8$ replications:

```
s <- 1e8L
m <- matrix(rexp((n + 1L)*s), s, n + 1L)
mean(rowSums((m/rowSums(m))[,2:n] > d/L) == 0)
#> [1] 0.00200159
```